# Get large Google Plus photo via URL change (lh3.googleusercontent.com)

Tags: url, random, google-plus

I am using Google Plus as a login, capturing users information etc.

The profile picture I am saving looks like the following :

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ahWlp0z8KQM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGA/nEfC5WjfVM4/photo.jpg

I am trying to get the various sizes e.g. small and large.

Is there some way I can just add an URL variable like `?size=small` or just a change in URL?? Is there any way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can also pass the `sz` query parameter to resize the image.

Passing `?sz=10` will resize the original image to a 10x10 image.

```
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ahWlp0z8KQM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGA/nEfC5WjfVM4/photo.jpg?sz=10
```

Comment: Thanks! Works too! Now we have two ways of doing this! :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Interesting to note, even if the url contains a size, like `https://..../VQXAoatgdUk/s100/photo.jpg` adding the request parameter like `?sz=400` will override it respectively the parameter is "stronger"

Answer (score 9):

You can specify the image size in the URL but it isn't a querystring parameter.

This is a link to a nice photo of moi:

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-CsrOQxw0XqI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGA/l87kTXQIMnQ/s230-c-k/photo.jpg

Notice the piece preceeding the photo name: `/s230-c-k/`

The number `230` reprisents the size of the image being retrived. Changing this will return an image with a width of that value for you.

In your case, something like:

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ahWlp0z8KQM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGA/nEfC5WjfVM4/s210-c-k/photo.jpg

Comment: Glad to have helped. The way I figued this out was to open up a small image and a large image in my browser and to look at what the URL differences were. As it happened the only difference was this number which, when i checked, coresponded to the size of the image.

Comment: Nice, I didn't even think of it, coz I am so caught up in the whole Facebook API. haha But thanks a lot!